# How do I extract text between two objects using XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, console

I'm using XPath to extract different web elements on a webpage, but have his a roadblock on one particular object that is sitting between two objects, but doesn't have a closing object behind it for a while.

I've been able to successfully extract other elements from the webpage, but don't know how to proceed at this point.

Here is a copy of what the HTML looks like from the Inspector:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="left_column">
                <div id="top">
                    <h1></h1>
                    #SOME TEXT
                <div>
                    <table>
                    .......
                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: So are you saying that your trying to get "#SOME TEXT"?

Comment: show how did you use Xpath

Comment: @Jeff Yes I am trying to get the text that is sitting between the table header and the second <div> on the page.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest here is how I am using XPath:
This is for a document under the second div called "guide", with several classes called "text"
    Xpath = "(//div[@id='guide']//span[contains(@class,'text')])[1]"
This is for another part of the page for a "trigger" class:
    Xpath2 = "(//div[contains(@class, 'widget')]//a[contains(@class, 'trigger')])"

Comment: @JackHubert, I don't see element with `id="guide"` within your fragment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought that I hope will help, but with out seeing the entire HTML I can't give more then just an idea. I have more experience with Selenium in java, so I am not 100% sure that python will have the same functionality but I imagine it does.

You should be able to get the text from any WebElement. In Java it would look something like this, but I imagine it should be too hard to change it to python

```
WebElement top = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='top']"));
String topString = top.getText();
```

If in your case your getting more then just the "#SomeText" you would need to remove the text from the other elements that you don't want. Something like:

```
WebElement topH1 = top.findElement(By.xpath("./h1"));
WebElement topInsideDiv = top.findElement(By.xpath("./div"));
String topHString = topH1.getText();
String topInsideDivString = topTable.getText();

//since you know that the H1 string would come first and the inside div 
//would come after you could take the substring of the topString
String result = topString.subString(topHString.length, 
                                    topString.length - topInsideDivString.length);
```

This is really just an idea on how you could do it. The way that you determine the part of the string that you would be interested in might need to be more complex. It could be that you just cycle through the strings to determine where you need to break apart the entire string to get what you want.  If there is text before the  tag you would need to be more complex about your solution, perhaps by searching for the text and discounting anything you find before it, but without that information I cant really help out more then this.